Selected Row changes when the published list is updated
My list is updated instantly when notifications come from a realtime database. But when I swipe to delete a row, if a new notification arrives, the selected row moves to the next row. What am I doing wrong ?
List{
                    ForEach(scanViewModel.notificationList.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        NotificationRow(
                            date: scanViewModel.notificationList[index].date,
                            message: scanViewModel.notificationList[index].message,
                            mid: scanViewModel.notificationList[index].mid,
                            appeared: scanViewModel.notificationList[index].appeared)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.BG)
                        .listRowInsets(.init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 20))
                        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                            /// DELETE BUTTON
                            Button {
                                indexID = scanViewModel.notificationList[index].id
                                islastDeletAlertShow = true
                            } label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                            }
                            .tint(Color.customRed)

                        }
}

I tried to save the ID of the selected index to prevent incorrect deletion, but I couldn't fix the error as an interface

You are instructing the ForEach to use the index of each item in the array as the id for layout. This would be OK, if the positions of items in the array never change. But by the sounds of it, the positions of items in the array do change, so this is not a good approach.
Try making the items Identifiable instead, then change it to:
ForEach(scanViewModel.notificationList) { notification in
   // ...
}


Dear Lord, I just set my model as Codable! Thank You So Much Benzy Neez!
